# Refresh metadata of cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I added nodes to a cluster which initialy used the wrong network interface as listen_adress. I fixed it by changeing the listen_address to the correct IP. The cluster is running well with that configuration but clients trying to connect to that cluster still receive the wrong IPs as Metadata from cluster. Is there any way to refresh metadata of a cluster whithout decommissioning the nodes and setting up new ones again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you may try to follow this advice: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_gossip_purge.html

You will need to restart the entire cluster on a rolling basis - one node at a time

If this does not work, try this on each node:

```
USE system;
SELECT * FROM peers;
```

Then delete bad records from the peers and restart the node, then go to the next node and do it again.