# Metadata is not refreshed after column is added

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

When I'm adding a column to an existing table (using cqlsh), many times my datastax-java-driver clients don't seem to notified of the changed schema. When a column is read by name, it seems that it is actually reading another column. This column always seems to be the column that is 'adjacent' to it.

For instance, if the table would originally have the columns a, c and d, and I would then add column b to it, then reading column d gives me the value of column c.

The only thing I can do is restart the client application, which solves the issue, but is very inconvenient. [The manual](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/manual/metadata/#refreshes%20manual) claims that third-party schema changes result in refreshing the meta data, but it does not seem to happen in my situation.

I'm using the 2.1.9 Java driver, and Cassandra 2.2.5.

Comment: There is a issue about it https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-560

Comment: Hope this help.
[See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28104550/refresh-metadata-of-cassandra-cluster)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be caused by https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-420, which is unresolved at this time. Fortunately, there is a rather simple workaround available.